Preload canvaskit.wasm file in parent domain and reuse (Cached version) in subdomain
To speed up flutter web first load time, I am preloading the canvaskit.wasm file hosted at cdn.xyz.com into  nextjs website hosted at for example xyz.com .Once user clicks any cta the domain switches and let's say it goes to my.xyz.com which has flutter web.
In the bootstrap.js I have added the same cdn url of canvaskit.wasm file so that ideally same cached wasm file can be used to speed up the first load.
Now the above stuff works properly when I open the websites in desktop browser but if I do it in the mobile phone every time I move from xyz.com to my.xyz.com the flutter gets the canvaskit file from the network instead of the memory cache.
In cloudlare adding cache rule like public, max age and immutable property.
Expected that the my.xyz.com domain uses the same cached wasm file which was preloaded in xyz.com
Actual Result.
It still gets the wasm file from the network even though in the parent domain cached file is present with the same url
